# Selecting 1 colour in image trace without clicking endlessly

Tags: adobe-illustrator

1. I've scanned a drawing that has lots of detail.
2. I've image traced it to the 30 colour maximum.
3. I've expanded it so it's editable.
4. I want to change the colours of this drawing.
5. Because there is so much detail with many colours right next to eachother, I have to do ENDLESS clicking to select a colour and change it.

Is there a way for me to just select something, and the programme to select every colour that is the same in the drawing out of the 30 colour limit so I can change the colours easily?

thanks for any replies!!!

Comment: Did you try **Edit -> Edit Colors -> Recolor Artwork...**?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select a color and then select every object that has the same fill, do the following:

Pick the Direct Select Tool (A), select the object to get the fill.

Go to Select -> Same -> Fill Color.